# CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch

Tags: css, security, 2019, cewp

I am working on client side web part using JavaScript and CSS for customization.

I have added custom css and JS into the page and I am getting the message on console of the browser i.e.

`CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch`

I checked the paths of the CSS files and all of them are correct. I searched over the internet for the same issue and applied following paths, but none of them worked.

- Installed the Core update in SharePoint available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57847).
- Installed the Language Update Pack available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100733)
- Checked the Static Content feature is installed in the machine
- Mime Type is available in IIS
- Checked the Registry for the CSS and it has proper file type mentioned i.e. text/css.

The above solutions did not work.

**The interesting part is**: when I am loading the same css from SharePoint Hive (15) it is loading properly.

Can someone please help me out for solving the issue.

**Environment**: SP2019 Windows Server 2019 Standard Evaluation

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone facing this problem, the solution is to go to

- Open Server Manager
- Add roles and features Role-based or
  feature-based installation

Click Web Server (IIS) -> Management Tools
-> check IIS 6 Management Compatibility